# Spring boot and ThymeLeaf:The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, dependencies, thymeleaf

When I want to run my application on Java, I have following problem:

```
2023-04-09 13:12:24.474  INFO 10620 --- [           main] c.e.a.SportsManagementSystemApplication  : Starting SportsManagementSystemApplication using Java 11.0.18 on Quizer with PID 10620 (C:\Users\akiri\IdeaProjects\SportsManagementSystemApplication\target\classes started by akiri in C:\Users\akiri\IdeaProjects\SportsManagementSystemApplication)
2023-04-09 13:12:24.477  INFO 10620 --- [           main] c.e.a.SportsManagementSystemApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-09 13:12:24.792  INFO 10620 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-09 13:12:24.826  INFO 10620 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 27 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-09 13:12:25.276  INFO 10620 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-04-09 13:12:25.281  INFO 10620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-04-09 13:12:25.281  INFO 10620 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2023-04-09 13:12:25.369  INFO 10620 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-09 13:12:25.369  INFO 10620 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 864 ms
2023-04-09 13:12:25.441  WARN 10620 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurity': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserDetailsService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService' defined in file [C:\Users\akiri\IdeaProjects\SportsManagementSystemApplication\target\classes\com\example\application\Security\CustomUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'users' defined in com.example.application.UserRepository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringSecurity: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#712ac7e6' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#712ac7e6': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2023-04-09 13:12:25.443  INFO 10620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-04-09 13:12:25.453  INFO 10620 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-09 13:12:25.462 ERROR 10620 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  springSecurity
↑     ↓
|  customUserDetailsService defined in file [C:\Users\akiri\IdeaProjects\SportsManagementSystemApplication\target\classes\com\example\application\Security\CustomUserDetailsService.class]
↑     ↓
|  users defined in com.example.application.UserRepository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringSecurity
↑     ↓
|  (inner bean)#712ac7e6
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SportApiDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.26</org.projectlombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.26</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>24.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is my Spring Security:

```
package com.example.application.Config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.application.UserRepository")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.application");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432/User");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("75801");

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

This is my CustomUserDetailsService:

```
package com.example.application.Security;

import com.example.application.Role.Role;
import com.example.application.User.User;
import com.example.application.UserRepository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (user != null) {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
        }else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    private Collection< ? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection <Role> roles) {
        Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRoles = roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return mapRoles;
    }
}
```

This is my UserRepository:

```
package com.example.application.UserRepository;

import com.example.application.User.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository(value="users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

    User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

This is my User:

```
package com.example.application.User;


import com.example.application.Role.Role;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Table(appliesTo = "users")
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USERS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLES_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

This is my Role:

```
package com.example.application.Role;


import com.example.application.User.User;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(appliesTo = "roles")
@Entity
public class Role
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Actually, I have already tried to add lazy annotation in my class but unfortunately it hasn't work.However I have already added permission in application.properties for spring that he can allow circular references in project and this is too hasn't helping me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).